# In Java/JSP, do we have some tools which will work same as Codeigniter Profiler

Tags: java, jsp, profiler

In Java/JSP, do we have some tools which will work same as Codeigniter Profiler.

Codeigniter Profiler includes

1. Number OF database calls made
2. Execution time for database call
3. Total Execution time
4. Total Memory used

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), it features a JDBC probe that shows database performance measurements:

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Comment: I think the OP wants this at runtime in production.  I usually think of JProfiler as a debugging tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what JMX was born for.  Expose your database bean as JMX and write it to maintain statistics.

Spring AOP would make such calculations easy.  Advise your persistence interface with an aspect to keep the code small, tight, and maintained in a single place.